# Raspberry Pi 4 not booting up after reboot

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian, reboot

I am having a brand new RPI4B and I am booting from a 128Gb SD card. My RPI is connected by a network cable directly to my WiFi router and I have configured static IP address in the `dhcpd.conf` file. The problem is that every time I issue `sudo reboot` command the RPI doesn't go up. I can recover it by re-plugging the network cable or by disconnecting the power for a couple of seconds. My issue looks to be very similar to this issue described on Github: [link](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3034) which despite being closed doesn't seem to be resolved.

I have tried the following steps:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade 
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt full-upgrade 
sudo rpi-update
```

If I switch to DHCP by commenting out the static IP address lines, I am still unable to connect to my Raspberry Pi after system reboot. 
Unfortunately, whatever I try I can't get my RPI to get back online after command-line reboot.

Comment: Perhaps there is something in the logs that might shed some light on this?

Comment: that was the problem there was nothing unusual in the logs. Everything looks perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was in the power supply I was using, which was coming with my phone and not an original one. Even though it was 5V, 4A every time I was issuing `sudo reboot` command it was simply shutting down the board and I needed to either re-plug the LAN cable or re-inserting the power supply.

I have exchanged the power supply with 5V, 2A from another phone and now it works perfectly fine and I was able to remotely and directly reboot the board without a hitch.

I guess this is coming from the implementation of the USB-C which is way more complex standard compared to micro USB.

Comment: fwiw, that has nothing to do with USB-C; your 5V, 4A PS is probably a fake and would fail even if connected directly to the pins 2-6 or 4-6; IMLE rp4 is very fastidious and is not easily fooled by power supplies not up to the spec. Try starting 4 times `while true; do true; done &`; if your 4A PS is _at least_ 1.5A, it should hold, and the rp should not crash or reboot ;-)

Comment: I think the problem is that I was using Dash charger from OnePlus and they have developed a proprietary standard for charging, which is apparently not compatible with the RPI4.